# Convert PHP Array of categories to HTML breadcrumbs for multiple sub categories

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, breadcrumbs

I have a PHP array of categories like this

```
$category = array(
    1 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parentID' => 0,
        'name' => 'SUV auto parts'
    ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'parentID' => 1,
            'name' => 'Engine Related'
        ),
            3 => array(
                'id' => 3,
                'parentID' => 2,
                'name' => 'Spark Plugs'
                        ),
            4 => array(
                'id' => 4,
                'parentID' => 2,
                'name' => 'Engine Oil'
                        ),
        5 => array(
            'id' => 5,
            'parentID' => 1,
            'name' => 'Body related'
        ),
    6 => array(
        'id' => 6,
        'parentID' => 0,
        'name' => 'Sedan auto parts'
    ),
        7 => array(
            'id' => 7,
            'parentID' => 6,
            'name' => 'Engine Related'
            ),
        );
```

I have managed to display the menu tree like this,

> ```
> SUV auto parts
> -- Engine Related
> ---- Spark Plugs
> ---- Engine Oil
> -- Body Related 
> Sedan auto parts
> -- Engine Related
> ```

I was trying to make breadcrumbs using https://stackoverflow.com/a/48598077/12677030

```
function breadcrumber($array,$id){
    static $result=[];  // declare the storage variable without losing elements during recursion
    if(isset($array[$id])){  // if target exists
        $result[]=$array[$id]['name'];  // store title text
        $parent=$array[$id]['parentID'];  // assign new target
        unset($array[$id]);  // remove possibility of an infinite loop
        breadcrumber($array,$parent);  // recurse
    }
    return $result;
}

echo implode(' -> ',breadcrumber(array_column($category,NULL,'id'),4));
```

Small function, works great but...

1. I can not figure out to display it with HTML /category.php?id=
2. It displays

> Engine Oil -> Engine Related -> SUV auto Parts

instead of which I want it to be like,

> SUV auto Parts -> Engine Related -> Engine Oil

I have also tried this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571259/12677030 Seems to solve both of my issues ..however this does not generate breadcrumbs for one parent one child.

> Sedan auto Parts -> Engine Related

Shows only when

> Parent Category -> Child Category -> Child category

I appreciate if someone will give any solution to rectify these issues.

---

expected output will be

[SUV auto Parts](/category/1) -> [Engine Related](/category/2) -> [Engine Oil](/category/4)

```
<a href="/category/1">SUV auto Parts</a> -> <a href="/category/2">Engine Related</a> -> <a href="/category/4">Engine Oil</a>
```

Or for only one child category;

[Sedan auto Parts](/category/6) -> [Engine Related](/category/7)

```
   <a href="/category/6">Sedan auto Parts</a> -> <a href="/category/7">Engine Related</a>
```

---

Comment: I think his question 1. about HTML, is he wants to wrap the breadcrumb name, in an `<a>` anchor tag with the url and category id inserted. Something thats pretty darn difficult with just using `implode`.

Comment: Although changing `$result[]=$array[$id]['name'];` to something like `$result[]='<a href="/category.php?id='. $array[$id]['id'] .'">'. $array[$id]['name'] .'</a>';` might work as you want?

Comment: @ggorlen I am expecting the output to be like, `<a href="/category/1">SUV auto Parts</a> -> <a href="/category/2">Engine Related</a> -> <a href="/category/4">Engine Oil</a>` or when I visit items under "Engine Related"   will be like `<a href="/category/6">Sedan auto Parts</a> -> <a href="/category/7">Engine Related</a>`

Comment: @IncredibleHat it worked perfect, 1st issue solve. I appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not figure out to display"? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for #1**

Credits to @IncredibleHat

replacing

```
$result[]=$array[$id]['name'];
```

with

```
$result[]='<a href="/category.php?id='. $array[$id]['id'] .'">'. $array[$id]['name'] .'</a>';
```

gives the output
[Engine Oil](/category.php?id=4) -> [Engine Related](/category.php?id=2) -> [SUV auto Parts](/category.php?id=1)

```
<a href="/category.php?id=4">Engine Oil</a> -> <a href="/category.php?id=2">Engine Related</a> -> <a href="/category.php?id=1">SUV auto Parts</a>
```

---

**Solution for #2**

Using PHP array funcion called **array_reverse**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

replace

```
return $result;
```

with

```
return array_reverse($result);
```

Now, Output will be;
[SUV auto Parts](/category.php?id=1) -> [Engine Related](/category.php?id=2) -> [Engine Oil](/category.php?id=4)

```
<a href="/category.php?id=1">SUV auto Parts</a> -> <a href="/category.php?id=2">Engine Related</a> -> <a href="/category.php?id=4">Engine Oil</a>
```